# MVC 4 Disable Client Image Caching

Tags: ios, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, caching

I am working on an MVC 4 app designed to run on iOS.  I have encountered a problem where the app crashes when the local cache exceeds 5MB (due to a very high number of images on the site).

I am trying to disable local caching, I have tried meta tags suggested in other posts and this does not work.  I have also tried decorating controller actions with

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 1, Location = OutputCacheLocation.None)]
```

This doesn't work because we use partial views and I get an exception saying that the location parameter is not supported on partial views.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up fixing this bug by using CSS Background Images rather than  tags.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried defining response headers? More specifically, the following header:

Cache-Control - This header must be present in the response from the server to enable HTTP caching by a client. The value of this header may include information like its max-age (how long to cache a response), and whether the response may be cached with public or private access, or no-cache (not at all). See the Cache-Control section of RFC 2616 for full details.